# Receive LiveView while recording movie EDSDK

Tags: edsdk

it's possible to get the view from the camera during the record ?
I have the liveview and when I swith to record mode, I lost the liveview, it's on the TFT of the camera, but I want to keep it on my application. It's possible ? If yes, how ?

Answer (score 0):

you need use this with OpenCV in threading loop reading from file which liveview is storing to directory at same time.